# VPS freeze every few days

Tags: ubuntu, unix, vps, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I have a recurring problem with one of my applications/servers i'm responsible for. I basically had one VPS with all the stack needed to run my application (nginx + postgresql + ruby + ruby on rails + passenger) maintained by ansible. There was a problem with that server has been like frozen once per 2 days. It was not receiving any incoming connections on port 80 nor 22 (so i was even not able to connect to it using ssh). The only solution was to reboot it. I have ignored that issue because i was sure there is something wrong with that machine directly and moving to the new one will fix the issue.

I've recently changed my ansible playbooks a bit and my application has been divided to 3 separate servers. I was sure the issue will not happen but, unfortunatelly, it's there again and, what's worse, it hits all three machines! I am using the same ansible role for basic server configuration of all those three servers but there is nothing that can be dangerous. Just basic stuff like user creation, generating SSH keys etc. Anyway, there is more - now, for those new three servers, even reboot can't fix that issue, after rebooting from Azure Panel, i'm still not able to connect to any of those three machines on 80 nor 22 ports.

I'm obviously not able to debug logs of those new servers cause they are unreachable but i still have the old one running so it might be helpful to check what's causing those freezes on it? I'm just not able to find anything in the logs (or i' don't know what and where should i look for any clues).

Servers uses Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

So many things could possibly be going wrong. Here's what I'd do:

- [Stay logged in](https://mosh.mit.edu/) and run `tail -f <every log file that might be helpful>`. You'll at least see the last things that happened when it died.
- Look at the logs after reboot. Also look at `dmesg`. You'll have to scroll waaaaay back to see the last event before the reboot.
- Look at the console logs. AWS delivers these in the EC2 Console (and via API), I don't know what Azure does with them.